# Loading Doctrine entity from generated class

Tags: symfony, doctrine, composer-php, mapping, auto-generate

I have Symfony project with Doctrine and entities located in **src/Entity**. Also, I have a script that appends some more logic (methods) to some of these classes. I'm trying to load by composer and Doctrine the generated classes and exclude the origins. The generated classes are located in **generated/{namespaceOfClasses}** e.g (**generated/App/User/User.php**).

#### Composer

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "App\\Entity\\": "generated/App/Entity",
    },
    "exclude-from-classmap": ["src/Entity/User/User.php"]
},
```

The User.php class is correctly mapped in **vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php**.

#### Doctrine

I'm not as familiar with Doctrine configuration and I have tried some configurations.

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
        App\Entity\User:
            type: annotation
            is_bundle: false
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/generated/App/Entity/User'
            prefix: 'App\Entity\User'
            alias: App
```

#### Error

When I want to generate Doctrine proxies, it fails with the message:

```
Class "App\Entity\User\User" sub class of "App\Entity\AbstractEntity" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

The **AbstractEntity** is parent of all entities...

Can anyone help me with the Doctrine configuration?

#### Edit

Another way (I'm not sure) is using origins when generating proxies and loading generated entities by composer for the common run of app. Is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How is this related to Composer?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry guys, now I noticed there was wrong class comment (annotation) in the generated classes. The generating script duplicates class comment. There was:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\User\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
/**
 * Generated class. DO NOT EDIT !!!
 *
 */
```

instead of:

```
/**
 * Generated class. DO NOT EDIT !!!
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\User\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
```